# Что лучше использовать в условие неравенства?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Раньше в условиях неравенства я всегда использовал *not*: `if not a == b` и подобное. Но на днях коллега, читая мой код, заставил меня начать сомневаться в правильности своих действий, напомнив про обязательную **читабельность кода** и давно забытую основу Python - `!=`. Возможно, я не прав, но до сих пор считаю, что *not* куда более интуитивно понятно и читабельно. Так как же всё-таки дружелюбнее кодить и что сказано по этому поводу в документации: есть ли смысл переучивать себя на `!=`?

Comment: Почему Вы считаете, что это _"давно забытая основа"_? Лично я считаю, что это повышает читабельность, использовать стоит. Ради любопытства заглянул в исходный код `Django`, при беглом осмотре, не заметил ни одной конструкции `not a == b`, а оператор `!=` использовался.

Comment: Если также есть ветка `else`, лучше поменять их местами, а условием сделать `if a == b`

Comment: @nomnoms12 давно забытая мной*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вопрос, как по мне, чисто дискуссионный, и однозначного ответа нет.
Всё-таки `!=` - более принятое решение для этой ситуации. Эталон своего рода.
Переучиваться или нет - дело лично ваше, но хочу предупредить: может, это и выглядит читабельно, когда у вас одно условие, но если у вас что-то вроде такого:

```py
if not a==b and not c==3 or a==b and c==3:
```

и так ещё несколько десятков условий, эти `not` сливаются с `and` и `or`.

Мне кажется, такой вариант выглядит более читабельным

```py
if a!=b and c!=3 or a==b and c==3:
```

А изменять привычки, или оставить всё как есть - решать вам

Answer (score 1):

Если мы говорим о сохранении читаемости текста, то надо смотреть не на простейшие, однозначные примеры, а на примеры в которых могут - по всяким причинам, начиная с неправильного понимания приоритетности до элементарной ошибки связанной с пропуском скобок -  возникнуть ситуации "неожиданной" интерпретации.

Ну например: понятно, что not a == 0  и a!=0  дадут один и тот-же результат.

А вот

```
a=276
not a == 0  == True
```

эквивалентно вот этому

```
a!=0 == True
```

или вот этому

```
a==0 != True
```

???

Оказывается нет, не эквивалентно - и ни тому, и ни другому.

А почему тогда

```
not a == 0  == False
```

эквивалентно

```
a!=0 == False
```

???

Я понимаю, что нужно расставить, скобки и пр.пр.пр.  Но если мы точно хотим не ошибиться в написании сложных конструкций *лучше* (не "*обязательно*", а просто "*лучше*", т.е. меньше вероятность ошибки и выше вероятность правильности понимания вашего кода читающим) *избегать* всего, что может вызвать сложности в интерпретации.